# Spark Avro to Parquet Writer

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, avro, parquet

Issue : object not serializable

Can you please see how to overcome the issue. able to read it properly like printing properly. but while writing the records to parquet getting

object not serializable

> caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter Serialization stack: - object not
>   serializable (class: parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter, value:
>   parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter@658e7ead)

Please review and let me know what are the best way to do it.

Code : Coverting Avro record to Parquet

```
  val records = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf.getConfiguration,
  classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]],
  classOf[AvroKey[GenericRecord]], //Transforms the PairRDD to RDD 
  classOf[NullWritable]).map(x => x._1.datum) 

  // Build a schema
  val schema = SchemaBuilder
  .record("x").namespace("x")
  .fields
  .name("x").`type`().stringType().noDefault()
  .endRecord

val parquetWriter = new AvroParquetWriter[GenericRecord](new Path(outPath), schema)

val parquet  = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema)

records.foreach { keyVal =>
  val x = keyVal._1.datum().get("xyz") -- Field
     parquet.set("x", x)
        .build
      parquetWriter.write(schema.build())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could start here to read in avro into a dataframe
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

```
// import needed for the .avro method to be added
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

// The Avro records get converted to Spark typesca
val df = sqlContext.read.avro("src/test/resources/episodes.avro")

df.registerTempTable("tempTable")
val sat = sqlContext.sql( //use lateral view explode )
sat.write.parquet("/tmp/output")
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `//use lateral view explode`? Why is this needed?

Comment: you have a column that is an array of three things. By using lateral view explode you can flatten that row but it will be three rows. All the columns will be the same except for the column that was an array. That will have three different values.

Comment: Why not `explode` alone (without lateral view)? I know I can do it with `explode` alone and have been wondering why to use a lateral view. You could also use `Dataset.flatMap`, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are taking the approach you are. But I would recommend a different approach. If you get the avro file into an rdd, which it looks like you do. And you can create a schema then convert the RDD into a data frame and then write the data frame out as parquet.

```
var avroDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(avroRDD,avroSchema)
avroDF
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .parquet("parquet directory to write file")
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. but issue is this is nested structure of array, list , map. Very large nested avro. so to flattern out  need to loop through all the elements and get whatever required.

Comment: it would be nice if you upvoted and accepted one of these answers. I answered every question you asked. @Ankur

Comment: I'm hitting this same NotSerializableException on AvroParquetWriter using foreach on the RDD because I'm trying to use a consistent Avro schema in the Parquet that is written out.  I haven't yet found a way to use Spark to read in a directory of Avro files with a known schema, and then create a Parquet version of the Avro data using that same schema.  I've tried @transient lazy on the AvroParquetWriter but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

For some of my complex Json that has complicated structs and arrays I use hive ql  lateral view explode. Here is an example of complex json that is flattened. It starts out as 10 rows and for some traces I can get 60 rows and some I get less than 5. It just depends on how it explodes.

```
val tenj = sqlContext.read.json("file:///home/marksmith/hive/Tenfile.json")

scala> tenj.printSchema
root

 |-- DDIVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EndTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Stalls: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Stall: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- StallType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TraceTypes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ActiveTicket: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Traces: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- EndTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- StartPayload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- SubticketID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- TicketID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- TicketState: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- StartTime: string (nullable = true)

tenj.registerTempTable("ddis")


val sat = sqlContext.sql(
    "select DDIVersion, StallsExp.stall, StallsExp.StallType, at.EndTime, at.ID, 
       at.Source, at.StartPayload.SubTicketId, at.StartPayload.TicketID, 
       at.StartPayload.TicketState, at.StartTime  
    from ddis 
      lateral view explode(Stalls) st as StallsExp 
      lateral view explode(StallsExp.TraceTypes.ActiveTicket.Traces) at1 as at")
sat: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DDIVersion: string, stall: bigint, StallType: string, EndTime: string, ID: string, Source: string, SubTicketId: string, TicketID: string, TicketState: bigint, StartTime: string]

sat.count
res22: Long = 10

sat.show
+----------+-----+---------+--------------------+---+------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------+
|DDIVersion|stall|StallType|             EndTime| ID|Source|SubTicketId|TicketID|TicketState|           StartTime|
+----------+-----+---------+--------------------+---+------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------+
|  5.3.1.11|   15|    POPS4|2016-06-08T20:07:...|   | STALL|          0|     777|          1|2016-06-08T20:07:...|
|  5.3.1.11|   14|    POPS4|2016-06-08T20:07:...|   | STALL|          0|     384|          1|2016-06-08T20:06:...|
|  5.3.1.11|   13|    POPS4|2016-06-08T20:07:...|   | STALL|          0|  135792|          1|2016-06-08T20:06:...|
|  5.0.0.28|   26|    POPS4|2016-06-08T20:06:...|   | STALL|          0|     774|          2|2016-06-08T20:03:...|
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can you please provide the way to read nested avro and fetch some specific columns and dump it to Parquet format...